# NEST mapping of Dictionary<string,List<string>>

Tags: dictionary, elasticsearch, mapping, nest

I have a class with `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as one of the members. I'm able to insert the data with automap, but unable to query the documents with the keys and/or values in the dictionary. If I use match query, it returns everything in the index. I tried using Terms, Nested/non-nested query, and QueryString query, but none of them returns any document.

```
class ESSchema
{
    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Machine { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Long, Store = false)]
    public long BatchNumber { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Environment { get; set; } = null;

    [Nested]
    //[Object(Store = false)]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> KeysValues { get; set; }
}
```

Automap converts the dictionary to the following mapping which I'm not sure is the correct representation of what I'm looking for.

```
"keysValues": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "comparer": {
            "properties": {

            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "count": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "keys": {
            "properties": {
                "count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "values": {
            "properties": {
                "count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "item": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: I've edited your question a bit. You should [edit] it further to add an actual question - so far it's only a problem statement, leaving readers to guess what you want specifically.

Answer (score 0):

When Automapping, [NEST by default will map one level down in the object graph.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#mapping-recursion) In the case of your `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` property, the public properties of the dictionary end up being mapped, which is undesirable.

There are a couple of ways this can be controlled

1.Passing `-1` for `maxRecursion` to `AutoMap()`

```
class ESSchema
{
    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Machine { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [Number(NumberType.Long, Store = false)]
    public long BatchNumber { get; set; }

    [String(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed, Store = false)]
    public string Environment { get; set; } = null;

    [Object(Store = false)]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> KeysValues { get; set; }
}

client.Map<ESSchema>(m => m
    .AutoMap(-1)
);
```

which results in

```
{
  "properties": {
    "machine": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": false,
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "filename": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": false,
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "batchNumber": {
      "type": "long",
      "store": false
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "store": false,
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "keysValues": {
      "type": "object",
      "store": false,
      "properties": {}
    }
  }
}
```

2.Controlling the mapping through fluent mapping overrides

```
client.Map<ESSchema>(m => m
    .AutoMap()
    .Properties(p => p
        .Object<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(o => o
            .Name(n => n.KeysValues)
            .Store(false)
        )
    )
);
```

Using `.Properties()` overrides any inferred mapping from Automapping.