# ElasticSearch/NEST indexing policy for Dictionary items

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a document model containing field which is a dictionary and can take any value, like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Permissions { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

For example

```
client.IndexDocument(new Document
{
    Id = "4",
    Description = "ordinary document",
    Metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "publish_date", new DateTime(1930, 10, 11) },
        { "author_country", "RU" },
        { "salary", 2590.00 },
        { "likes", 23 },
    }
})
```

Mapping is done automatically so default analizers change values of dictionary, e.g.: change strings to lowercase or remove dashes so this code won't return any results:

```
var result = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q =>
        q.Term(new Field("metadata.author_country"), "RU"))
    );
```

How can i disable this behaviour for any value of Metadata? Or- set custom analizer? Or- disable it only for values of given type?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the mapping of the document fields to the correct kind.
See more info here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping.html
And all the types are listed here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping-types.html

To do it in Nest you need to add the correct attribute to your document definition.

See the details here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html

If I understand what you are trying to do then you will need to set the Metadata type as nested because you want to search the Metadata:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Elastic does auto mapping on all fields - and it works ok. I just want to customize this behaviour. I just observed another strange thing. Nested field is mapped dynamically only when named `Metadata`. When I added another nested field with same `Dictionary<string, object>` type (`Dictionary<string, object> Permissions {get;set;}`) it is not mapped as exected (it's elements are mapped to `unknown type`). Why is that? How can I change this?

Comment: Just change the mapping with attributes in the Document class definition: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html

Comment: Can you be more precise? I tried adding `[Object]` and `[Nested]` to my `Permissions` property - after recreating index kibana still shows it a `unknown type` on values from this property.

Comment: I've created a screenshot to visualize my problem: https://ibb.co/qrRNch9

Comment: The Permissions field is configured under document ? it should auto map it just like the Metadata then

Comment: You can change the automap max recursion levels and it can resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515870/nest-mapping-of-dictionarystring-liststring?rq=1 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/auto-map.html#mapping-recursion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228525/discussion-between-krzysztof-and-alex-s).