# Dictionary field with name "Metadata"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This question stems from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119494/elasticsearch-nest-indexing-policy-for-dictionary-items) but i think it deserves separate thread.

In my document model i've created two fields of type `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
public class Document 
{
    // some fields ....
    public Dictionary<string, object> Permissions { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using default indexing policy (let elastic handle mapping).

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9200"));
    settings.EnableDebugMode();
    settings.DefaultMappingFor<Document>(m => m
        .IndexName("documents")
    );
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    foreach (var doc in SampleDocuments.Documents)
    {
        var result = client.IndexDocument(doc);

        Console.WriteLine($"Indexing {doc.Name}: {result.IsValid}");
    }
}
```

Now, looking at my documents from kibana i've noticed that only fields from `Metadata` field are mapped dynamically. Those from `Permissions` field are of `unknown type`.

[image: Kibana screenshot]

Notice the icons on the left. Further investigation showed that changing `Metadata` field name to anything else (like `Metadata1`) disables auto detecting types (it is indexed in a same manner as `Permissions`).

My question is: what is so special about that name? Secondary question is: how can I force elastic to index `Permissions` field in the same way as `Metadata`? I've tried adding `[Nested]` and `[Object]` mapping, also setting max recursion level in `AutoMap()` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to [refresh your index pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html#_refresh_the_data_fields) in Stack Management > Index patterns > Refresh to make sure the latest mapping changes are picked up.

Also worth noting that as of 7.11.0, the [refresh button has disappears](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/92361) as the index patterns are now refreshed automatically whenever needed.